# Phonegap - Local file gets opened in the main view instead of within an iframe

Tags: android, iframe, cordova

I'm developing an Android app with PhoneGap 2.0, which opens locally stored Html's in an iframe. The problem is that whenever I try to load any Html, it will be displayed, but the app breaks (no more Javascript is executed). This is what I get in the logcat:

```
09-12 12:14:43.374: D/CordovaWebView(19771): >>> loadUrlNow()
09-12 12:14:43.394: D/CordovaLog(19771): JSCallback Error: Request failed.
09-12 12:14:43.394: D/CordovaLog(19771): file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/cordova-2.0.0.js: Line 3698 : JSCallback Error: Request failed.
09-12 12:14:43.394: I/Web Console(19771): JSCallback Error: Request failed. at file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/cordova-2.0.0.js:3698
09-12 12:14:43.414: D/DroidGap(19771): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///storage/sdcard0/file.html)
09-12 12:14:43.584: D/chromium(19771): Unknown chromium error: -6
09-12 12:14:43.704: D/Cordova(19771): onPageFinished(file:///storage/sdcard0/file.html)
09-12 12:14:43.704: D/CordovaWebView(19771): >>> loadUrlNow()
09-12 12:14:43.714: D/DroidGap(19771): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
09-12 12:14:43.714: D/DroidGap(19771): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///storage/sdcard0/file.html)
```

EDIT:

What is actually happening, is that the whole app html is replaced by the file's one. That's why the Javascript wasn't executing... there was no Javascript. This said, does anyone know how to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, although it's not optimal... it consists of changing the Cordova/PhoneGap source code and compiling it. I DON'T KNOW THE CONSEQUENCES of these modifications, just that it seems to work.
The file to modify is org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.java. It's needed to comment a bunch of lines and returning `false` at the end. This is the snippet:

```
    // All else 
    //        else { 
    // 
    //            // If our app or file:, then load into a new Cordova webview container by starting a new instance of our activity. 
    //            // Our app continues to run.  When BACK is pressed, our app is redisplayed. 
    //            if (url.startsWith("file://") || url.indexOf(this.ctx.baseUrl) == 0 || ctx.isUrlWhiteListed(url)) { 
    //                this.ctx.loadUrl(url); 
    //            } 
    // 
    //            // If not our application, let default viewer handle 
    //            else { 
    //                try { 
    //                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    //                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
    //                    ctx.startActivity(intent); 
    //                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) { 
    //                    LOG.e(TAG, "Error loading url "+url, e); 
    //                } 
    //            } 
    //        } 
    //        return true; 
    return false;
```

I've got the solution from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/A2Ow3QSGhBE)